# QNetworkAccessManager and Xml reply

Tags: xml, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

I was trying to send a request using QNetworkAccessmanager  to localhost/conductor/api/provider_accounts.xml but the problem is when I open it with my browser then I get the appropriate output but when I do the same with QNetworkAccessmanager then I am not getting anything  at all. Here is my code

```
  void ServiceProvider::replyFinished(QNetworkReply * reply)
 {
 qDebug()<<reply->readAll();
 QString data=(QString)reply->readAll();
 qDebug()<<data;
 QXmlStreamReader xml(data);
 QXmlStreamAttributes attrib;
    while(!xml.atEnd()){
        xml.readNextStartElement();
        if(xml.name()=="name" && !xml.isEndElement()){
            attrib=xml.attributes();
            QString name=attrib.value("name").toString();
            qDebug()<<name;
            }
    }
}

void ServiceProvider::pushImage()
{
manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("https://localhost/conductor   
/api/provider_accounts.xml")));
connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
}
```

Comment: You are using the link with https protocol. Did you try to connect the SSLErrors signal and see what is the error? U mite have to install OpenSSL.

Answer (score 0):

You can't read the reply twice:

```
qDebug()<<reply->readAll();
QString data=(QString)reply->readAll();
```

The `qDebug()` line above will consume all the data. The second call you have to `readAll()` is also incorrect, since that returns a `QByteArray`. You can't simply cast it to `QString` as you do above and expect it to work. You need to check the encoding of the reply and use on of the appropriate conversion functions such as `QString::fromUtf8(reply->readAll())`.

Comment: As I had already written that I am not getting anything at all , even from the first readAll() .